# dup2 vs close+open for stdout redirection

Tags: linux, stdout, system-calls, dup

Redirecting stdout with `close` and `open`:

```
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
int fd = open("log", O_RDWR);
printf("My output\n");
```

differs from redirection through `dup2`:

```
int fd = open("log", O_RDWR);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
printf("My output\n");
```

with `strace` i see that in the first case `write` returns `EBADF`:

```
$ strace -e write ./a.out
write(1, "My output\n", 10)        = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

How `dup2` differs from `open`+`close`?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
int fd = open("log", O_RDWR);
```

The open file can be any file descriptor. Just because you closed STDOUT_FILENO does not mean it will be used for `open()`. Even if the system chose the first available descriptors (something that's not guaranteed), it is still possible that:

- stdin is closed as well and would get chosen first.
- a signal is run in between the `close()` and `open()` and the signal handler opens a file.
- the `open()` fails, leaving you with a closed stdout.

The `dup2()` version on the other hand ensures the file descriptor will be the correct one, by specifiying it explicitly. In addition, `dup2()` is guaranteed to be atomic. That is, at any point in time, STDOUT_FILENO is valid and either it's still the old one, or it is the new one and old one has been closed.

As a sidenote, after a `dup2`, both descriptor numbers refer to the same file, and both need to be `close()`ed. So if you're just redirecting stdout, you probably want to `close(fd)` after the `dup2()` call.

Comment: I asked this question having verified that `fd` returned by `open` is equal to `STDOUT_FILENO`. The delivery of a signal yes, is possible but it is not this the case. Since no one of your scenario is here, in what the two method are different?

Comment: POSIX guarantees that open uses the lowest available fd